# How to export data in an excel file with specific column names from a dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have made a dic like follow:

```
number_of_c_in_level_ = dict()

for x in range(1,50):
  number_of_c_in_level_[x]=x*2
```

How I can export those data in an excel file which has the column name as bellow

```
number_of_c_in_level_1  number_of_c_in_level_2  ...   number_of_c_in_level_50
2                        4                      ...         100
```

[or, please see an exemplar  final excel file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj92n.png)

Comment: just note that ```range(1,50)``` is the interval ```[1,50)```. It means 50 is not included in the range. Also in your example ```2*1``` is written as 1, but it should be 2

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `pandas` module to create a DataFrame(similar to excel) as per your need.

DataFrame object in pandas module can accept dictionary object as an input and will convert into excel look a like structure. See the below demo for better understanding..

```
import pandas as pd # module required for the DataFrame operations
```

```
print(number_of_c_in_level_)

{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, ...., 48: 96, 49: 98}
```

Before converting into DataFrame, change the dictionary `key : values` as required in the output.

**Note:**
Dictionary values should be in the form of array(Lists) to get a expected DataFrame.

```
Req_Change = {"number_of_c_in_level_"+str(i):[j] for i,j in number_of_c_in_level_.items()}
```

The above code makes the required column name format and the values in the form of arrays.

```
print(Req_Change)

{'number_of_c_in_level_1': [2], .... , 'number_of_c_in_level_49': [98]}
```

Now we can convert this Dictionary into DataFrame with the below step,

```
Export = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

```
print(Export)

number_of_c_in_level_1  number_of_c_in_level_2  ... number_of_c_in_level_49
2                       4                                98
```

Finally lets Export the DataFrame into Excel / csv,

**Note: To Export into Excel, you might need `openpyxl` module. So you can export into csv and change it into Excel format later**

```
Export.to_excel("Export.xlsx",index=False)

Export.to_csv("Export.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the text in the key part of the dictionary, convert to a dataframe and then write it to CSV or Excel (I recommend CSV because it is a more universal format). Here is your code edited to the version:

```
import pandas as pd

number_of_c_in_level_ = dict()

for x in range(1,51):
  number_of_c_in_level_['number_of_c_in_level_' + str(x)] = 2*x

df = pd.DataFrame(number_of_c_in_level_, index=[0])
with open('result2.csv','w')  as csv_file:
    df.to_csv(csv_file,index=False)
```